# SQLite/Room ORDER BY with a CASE statement ignores column COLLATE

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, case, android-room, collation

Theres something I don't understand with regards to a `CASE` statement in a `ORDER BY` clause using SQLite (initially I was using it with Android Room but its not specific to that).

This is a distillation of the problem.  Query 1 returns what I was expecting (a case insensitive, ordered list of the stuff).  Whereas Query 2 appears to ignore the column's COLLATE NOCASE.  Why is that?

Thanks!

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "stuff" TEXT COLLATE NOCASE,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

INSERT INTO test (stuff) VALUES ("0");
INSERT INTO test (stuff) VALUES ("a");
INSERT INTO test (stuff) VALUES ("z");
INSERT INTO test (stuff) VALUES ("A");
INSERT INTO test (stuff) VALUES ("Z");
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY
    stuff ASC;
```

| id | stuff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | a |
| 4 | A |
| 3 | z |
| 5 | Z |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN true THEN stuff END ASC;
```

| id | stuff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | Z |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | z |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5MBfSgBZEBtjek4n9WtPSj/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of any [CASE expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_case_expression) is an *expression*, even if its return value is a simple reference to a column like `THEN stuff`.
For this returned expression there is no explicitly defined [Collating Sequence](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collating_sequences), so for the purposes of the `ORDER BY` clause comparisons the collating sequence that is used is `BINARY`.

The same would happen if the `ORDER BY` clause was just:

```
ORDER BY stuff || '' ASC
```

The above expression `stuff || ''` returns just the value of the column `stuff`, but still it is considered an *expression* and the `BINARY` collating sequence will be used.

If you want to apply a specific collating sequence to the result of the `CASE` expression you must use it explicitly in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN true THEN stuff END COLLATE NOCASE ASC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2d516993dc5b2d99548e212fae4b1702).

Comment: Thanks.  Thats a great answer.  I was half expecting a “why do you want to do that?” job!